# using `rlang` for conditional labelling in `ggplot` using `ggrepel`

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang, ggrepel

I am writing a custom function to create a scatterplot with labels attached to points. Here is a minimal rendition of the same.

```r
# needed libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# custom function
label_adder <- function(data, x, y, label.var) {
  # basic plot
  plot <-
    ggplot(data = data,
           mapping = aes(
             x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
             y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
           )) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")

  # adding label
  plot <-
    plot +
    geom_label_repel(mapping = aes(label = !!rlang::enquo(label.var)))

  return(plot)
}

# creating dataframe
mtcars_new <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(., var = "car") %>%
  tibble::as_data_frame(x = .)

# using the function
label_adder(
  data = mtcars_new,
  x = wt,
  y = mpg,
  label.var = car
)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

**Question**
I can't seem to figure out how I can make the labeling conditional on values of `x` and `y` variables. For example, let's say the user wants not to display all points in the scatterplot but only the points with (examples):

```r
wt > 5
wt < 4 & mpg < 20
wt > 4 | mpg > 25
```

etc.

What can I change in the code for `geom_label_repel` using `rlang` so that any condition the user provides (involving `x` and/or `y`) will be evaluated and only those labels will be displayed in the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this. Here I add an expression argument to your function, check if the expression is being used, then filter accordingly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# custom function
label_adder <- function(data, x, y, label.var, exp = NULL) {
  param_list <- as.list(match.call())

  if("exp" %in% names(param_list)){
    plot <-
    ggplot(
           mapping = aes(
             x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
             y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
           )) +
    geom_point(data = data) +
    geom_smooth(data = data, method = "lm")+
    geom_label_repel(data = data %>% filter(!!rlang::enquo(exp)), 
                     mapping = aes(label = !!rlang::enquo(label.var)))
    return(plot)
  }
  else{
    plot <-
    ggplot(data = data,
           mapping = aes(
             x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
             y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
           )) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
    geom_label_repel(mapping = aes(label = !!rlang::enquo(label.var)))

  return(plot)
  }
}

# creating dataframe
mtcars_new <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(., var = "car") %>%
  tibble::as_data_frame(x = .)

# using the function
label_adder(
  data = mtcars_new,
  x = wt,
  y = mpg,
  label.var = car
)
```

[image]

```
label_adder(
  data = mtcars_new,
  x = wt,
  y = mpg,
  label.var = car,
  exp = wt < 4 & mpg < 20
)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-30 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

**Update**

```
label_adder <- function(data, x, y, label.var, exp = NULL) {
  param_list <- as.list(match.call())

  if("exp" %in% names(param_list)){
    my_exp <- rlang::enquo(exp)
  }
  else{
    a <- "row_number() > 0"
    my_exp <- rlang::quo(!! rlang::sym(a))
  }

  plot <-
    ggplot(
           mapping = aes(
             x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
             y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
           )) +
    geom_point(data = data) +
    geom_smooth(data = data, method = "lm")+
    geom_label_repel(data = data %>% filter(!!my_exp), 
                     mapping = aes(label = !!rlang::enquo(label.var)))
  return(plot)

}
```

This still uses an `if` and `else`, but does not require all the extra code like above.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering if there is any possibility to avoid `if-else`. That is, the function will work irrespective of whether `exp` argument is `NULL` or not. The example I've given is pretty simple and so this doesn't seem like a big deal, but my actual function is big and including an `if-else` will complicate it even further.

Comment: No I definitely understand that. I find thats a common issue. Let me thing about it for a minute and come up with another solution.

Comment: I updated with a small tweak for space. As a side note, If your script for the function is very long. You can write separate functions for each part of the larger function  and then have the larger function call the individual small functions. I find that helps to de-clutter long functions

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand what this part is supposed to do ```else{
    a <- "row_number() > 0"
    my_exp <- rlang::quo(!! rlang::sym(a))
  }```.

Comment: In order to avoid the long if-else statement, you need to be able to have a default “filter” that includes all the data. row_number >0 includes all the data

Comment: I see. The reason I asked because the function fails if I use it with `purrr::map` and don't specify `label.expression` argument. The error it gives is `Evaluation error: Evaluation error: object 'row_number() > 0' not found..`. So it seems like when used as an anonymous function inside a map, it doesn't enter the `else` part. There is no problem though if I **do** specify `label.expression`.

Comment: Should I post it as a separate question with a new example?

Comment: Ahh I see. Yes, map is going to look row wise so referencing a row number as the expression would fail. You could modify the else expression to make it more general. You could also open a new question using map in the example and ping me to take a look

Comment: I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117181/properly-evaluating-rlang-expression-inside-list-column